# Silver Nitrate Solution + Flame = Mirror?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, silver

I purchased an interesting product recently, which says it contains: "Isopropyl alocohol, silver nitrate, Water-based lacquer". You apply it to a smooth surface, then use a blowtorch on it and it'll darken before turning into a mirror. I can't find any information about this reaction, the closest I can find is Tollens Test. What is this reaction and how does it work?

Comment: how to make silver adhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to [Brashear's process](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GOVPUB-C13-096f3afbeff3555475537c8991ac3ce6/pdf/GOVPUB-C13-096f3afbeff3555475537c8991ac3ce6.pdf). Brashear's process *does* use Tollen's reagent, though as described, this is a variant.

Consider that $\ce{AgNO3}$ is easily reduced to silver metal.

[Tollen's reagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tollens%27_reagent) (diamminesilver(I) coordination complex $\ce{[Ag(NH3)2]+}$) is **very** easily reduced, just needing room temperature glucose or other aldehyde to create a silver mirror. In fact, the reagent is *too* unstable to be sold as a premixed product.

In that kit, it would seem the lacquer (dissolved in isopropanol), plus any remaining isopropanol that has not boiled off during heating, reduces the $\ce{AgNO3}$ to metallic silver when heated strongly.

BTW, you might edit your question to describe the use of the product, how well the mirror is formed, and how long it lasts -- if the lacquer burns off, silver quickly tarnishes.

Also, note that absolutely, scrupulously clean glass is needed, or the silver does not adhere.